# Magento 2 Tests in Magento

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests, mtaf

We are looking to start using testing for our builds and are looking at the best tools to use. I noticed there is a port of the Magento 2 tests https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting and had a bit of play around last night. There are a lot of skipped tests but it did work. I like the idea that we would be writing tests in the same way that Magento is heading, but I'm concerned that it's either going to change or the backport's missing functionality means it's not worthwhile.

Is it a good idea to use Magento 2 tests or would it be more beneficial to go with the Ecomdev PHPUnit? Are there any recommendations for other types of testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento has released the Magento Test Automation Framework with tests for CE 1.7.0.2 and it was also used by the community during the March 2013 bugathon where the CE 1.8 alpha was worked on by community developers.

I would suggest checking out the official MATF before attempting to use one of the community ports of the Magento 2.0 test suite, all of which were put together before Magento released their own back-ported version of the testing suite which they started using internally after having built it initially for Magento 2.0.

Here are some links with information on it:

- [Magento Tests Automation Framework](https://github.com/magento/taf)
- [A PDF User Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/download/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkUsersGuide.pdf)
- [How It Works from Bugathon Wiki](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki/QA-Tools-&-Framework)
- [Example QA Test](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki/QAExample)
- [MATF Presentation](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3905529/MTAF%20v3.pptx)
- [Best practices to write automated tests using MTAF](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki/Best-practices-to-write-automated-tests-using-MTAF)

Comment: Thank you for the reply - very handy and I'll have a read through. Are Magento going to continue using the TAF when Magento 2 comes out or do they have a different setup?

Comment: As an added bonus, MTAF will turn your computer into a combination hair blowdryer / harrier jet. That's a nice feature.

Comment: The tests are different, but the setups are (I believe) very similar. I would expect them to continue using them indefinitely now that they exist, and know they have been using automated testing and profiling to enable better performance optimization as they continue work on Magento 2

Comment: @philwinkle I've heard that…

Comment: ... @benmarks said he melted down his MBP with them. Unfortunately, I've not taken the time to do the same yet. :P

Comment: If it melts a computer you know it's working.

Comment: @davidalger That's good to know. We did have a dabble about a year ago but we'll give it another look.